# How correctly work with JWT and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I just start working with node app. For authentification I use JWT. So I have a question, how correctly work with it on UI and Backend side.

For example I get token, save it on session storage and then I send request for some collection for current user.
The question is - Does it need to store user name also in request or I can understand what user send request by token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend - there are lots of tutorials online about this, e.g.

- https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth
- https://egghead.io/series/angularjs-authentication-with-jwt

Comment: perfect, i don't read all info about JWT. Thank for answer :)